# What is my cat trying to say and why is she refusing food from me?

Tags: cats, behavior

Today morning when I was working on my study table. My cat jumped on the table. She started to meow. Then she started to lick my cheeks and nose. Then she started to put her paws on my cheeks and nose. Unable to get what she is trying to convey I put some food on her plate. She kept looking at it from top of table. I brought her down and put her by the side of the plate. But still she didn't eat anything. I tried to persuade her to eat but she didn't. I started to caress her but still she didn't eat.

After sometime I put the food back in box and went on to study. She also climbed the table and started doing the same things again. Then I started to play with her and she really enjoyed it. But as soon as I got back to work, she climbed the table and stared doing the the same things again.

Now I asked my mom for help. She came. The moment she entered the room, my cat instantly started meowing at her at the top of her voice. My mom gave her food on plate. She jumped by the side of the plate and started making loud purring sound. But instead of eating she kept looking at my mom and kept meowing. My mom started caressing her and instantly she started eating vigorously as if she is extremely hungry.

After eating a handsome amount she stopped eating and tried to bring down the whiskas dry food to floor with her paws. Now my mom started to place the food piece by piece on floor. And she again stared eating and again ate a handsome amount. After she had enough food and was full, she went to my bed and went to sleep.

Now I am unable to understand any of her behaviors. Anybody got any idea?

Comment: Is the cat spayed? This DOES sound like behaviour that can happen in heat.

Comment: Yes she had her surgery